# Showing uniform convergence to origin in 3rd quadrant for $x(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}-t}$ as $t\ \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

I want to show that for the system $\dot{x}=x^2, \dot{y}=y^2$,any solutions starting in the 3rd quadrant not including 0, converge uniformly to the origin.
For an initial point $(x_0,y_0)$, (note both $x_0$ and $y_0$ are negative as we are considering in the 3rd quadrant), we have solutions to the system as
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}-t}, y(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y_0}-t}$$
Let's just consider the  x(t) (as y(t) will be similar). As $x_0$ is negative, let us say that $x_0<-\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon>0$.

To show the uniform convergence, I want to show that

$$\sup_{x_0 \leq -\epsilon} |x(t)| \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } t\rightarrow \infty$$
$$=\sup_{x_0 \leq -\epsilon} \frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{x_0}}$$

But I am not sure where to go from here. 
Could I write 
$$=\sup_{x_0 \leq \epsilon} \frac{x_0}{x_0t-1} \leq \frac{-\epsilon}{-\epsilon t -1} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon t+1} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } t \rightarrow \infty$$?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_0 \leqslant -\epsilon < 0$ then

$$\left| \frac{1}{ 1/x_0-t}\right| = \left| \frac{-1}{ t - 1/x_0}\right| =\frac{1}{t + 1/|x_0|} \leqslant \frac{1}{t}$$

Given $\epsilon_0 > 0$, if $t > 1/\epsilon_0$ then for all $x_0 \leqslant -\epsilon$ we have

$$\left| \frac{1}{1/x_0 - t}\right| < \epsilon_0.$$

Therefore, convergence to $0$ is uniform.